# Google compute load balancer throws 400 Bad Request on DELETE

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created an instance group through an instance template, and aligned this instance group to a backend service which is used by a http load balancer.

Now when I open a url to an instance vm from the instance group I created, I can do `GET` `POST` and `DELETE` requests and all of the requests are fast, and everything works as expected.

When I open up the url to the static IP for the load balancer.  I can do `GET` and `POST` requests, but `DELETE` requests throw a `400 BAD REQUEST` with a response page saying:

> That’s an error.
>
> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we
>   know.

Other load balancer issues:

- The site is quite slow through the load balancer.  Perhaps
  there is a setting I'm missing, I'm pretty sure I set everything to
  us-central-1b.
- Sometimes the site doesn't even show up.  It will work for http, but then
  it won't work for https and visa versa.  The load balancer has very strange
  behaviour.

My VM api access is set to **This instance has full API access to all Google Cloud services**

I'm using Django as my api layer, I turned on debugging on this host and saw that the `DELETE` requests weren't even coming through when making requests through the loadbalancer static ip.  Is there a firewall setting I'm missing?

Please help me make this fast again and allow the `DELETE` requests to happen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sending anything in the body of the request?

Google load balancer will respond with `400 BAD REQUEST` if you try to send anything in the body. Easy way to check if this is the problem is fire up Chrome Developer tools and check the Request Payload section is empty/doesn't exist.

The HTTP spec doesn't explicitly say wether you can pass anything in the body so this isn't wrong, just undefined.

Is the load balancer slow for all requests or just pages with lots of elements on?

Comment: This was a godsend...all delete requests in my app broke after moving our servers behind a google cloud load balancer and it turned out to be because of this idiotic move by google. The HTTP 1.1 spec allows for a body in DELETE requests, I don't get why they thought it was a smart idea to return a 400 error for a perfectly acceptable request. :(

Comment: I would also report that the same issue occurs with Google App Engine. DELETE requests cannot carry any payload. Kudos for the nice catch!

Comment: this is valid for GET requests too