# GET request with body rejected by GKE

Tags: kubernetes, get, google-kubernetes-engine, fastapi

I am running a FastAPI backend service on GKE. There's a legacy endpoint that uses a `GET` request with body attached to it. I know that `GET` requests are not supposed to have a body, but this is a legacy endpoint used by a library therefore I have no choice but to support it.

Currently when a `GET` request with body is send to GKE, I get the following response:
[image]

I have tested the endpoint locally and it works without issues. I don't know exactly what the issue is but GCP is definitely intercepting the request at some point and rejecting it due to it having a body.

The only workaround I can think of currently is using a some sort of proxy and converting the request before it reaches GKE. Unfortunately, I'm not a GCP expert.

Has anyone had any experience tackling an issue like this? What would be an optimal solution here, granted that the endpoint has to be supported currently?

**EDIT**: Added ingress config:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: XXX
  namespace: XXX
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: XXX
    #ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - 'XXX'
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: XXX
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: XXX
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: XXX
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Seems a message from the k8s ingress. Can you post the ingress configuration? maybe using a nginx ingress would do the trick.

Comment: @IñigoGonzález Just added the ingress config. Hid sensitive info with `XXX`

Comment: Confirmed. This message is originated by Google. As a workaround you coud use a NodePort to expose the API service... or use an nginx ingress service https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/intro/how-nginx-ingress-controller-works/

Comment: According to the official documentation [1] there are two possible scenarios where the LB is blocking the GET request, 1) The request method does not allow a body, but the request has one or 2) Body chunks are unparseable. This is the only case where some data reaches the backend. The load balancer closes the connections to the client and backend when it receives an unparseable chunk. [1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#illegal_request_and_response_handling

Comment: You could try to modify your GET request using a proxy, or use a different ingress controller as is stated in the comment above. Considering moving your legacy endpoint to the cloud is an option too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response from the Google Load Balancer, which is configured the the GKE Ingress resource. I don't think that this can be configured in a way that it accepts that request.

You might try using another Ingress controller that doesn't reject such malformed requests.

See also [Google compute load balancer throws 400 Bad Request on DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135180/google-compute-load-balancer-throws-400-bad-request-on-delete)